# How do I access an environment variable from within the public folder?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

In my create-react-app app I have a javascript file in my public folder. Within it, I need to access an environment variable named `REACT_APP_ACTUAL_ENV` but I'm not sure how I can. Trying the usual `process.env.REACT_APP_ACTUAL_ENV` doesn't work because `process` is undefined in the public folder. Looking at https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables, I can do `%REACT_APP_ACTUAL_ENV%` within an HTML file in the public folder and it works just fine. But the problem is I need to do this within a javascript file somehow, though I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it in a js file?

Comment: Sadly, no. I had to find a workaround that involves communicating through local storage.

Comment: Refer to this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#referencing-environment-variables-in-the-html

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have to reference `REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID` environment variable to initialize Facebook SDK inside `public/index.html` file.

I simply assign the variable to HTML element's property then access it using JavaScript like so:

```html
...
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="%REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID%" />

<script>
   const facebookAppId = document.querySelector('[property="fb:app_id"]').content;
   // use `facebookAppId` here
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably sufficient for most use cases but, if I recall correctly, I needed to access the environment variable from within an extension's background script, so scripting from within an HTML file wouldn't have worked. It has to be from within a .js file, which may be impossible.